# Fixed-point arithmetic

Tags: python, math

Does anyone know of a library to do fixed point arithmetic in Python?
Or, does anyone has sample code?

Comment: I think he means fixed point.  I have to ask why?  Because if its for performance, you won't get any.

Comment: I have to write an emulation library for algorithm calculations to be implemented in an FPGA (so, no FP support)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are interested in doing fixed point arithmetic, the Python Standard Library has a [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module that can do it.

Actually, it has a more flexible floating point ability than the built-in too. By flexible I mean that it:

- Has "signals" for various exceptional conditions (these can be set to do a variety of things on signaling)
- Has positive and negative
  infinities, as well as NaN (not a
  number)
- Can differentiate between positive
  and negative 0
- Allows you to set different rounding
  schemes.
- Allows you to set your own min and
  max values.

All in all, it is handy for a [million household uses](http://www.skepticfiles.org/en001/monty16.htm).

Comment: ?? The Decimal pkg lets you define the precision but it is base10 precision.  You can state 6 digits to the right of the decimal point.  For doing hardware modeling you want to define the number of bits, the precision is defined by the number of base2 digits to the right of the binary point.  Curious, how the Decimal package was a good solution.

Answer (score 7):

The [deModel](http://www.dilloneng.com/demodel.html) package sounds like what you're  looking for.

Comment: Another fixed-point package is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/cfelton/fixed_point/overview)

Comment: Is the numpy wrapper as fast as built in numpy types uses object type?

Answer (score 4):

Another option worth considering if you want to simulate the behaviour of *binary* fixed-point numbers beyond simple arithmetic operations, is the [spfpm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spfpm) module. That will allow you to calculate square-roots, powers, logarithms and trigonometric functions using fixed numbers of bits. It's a pure-python module, so doesn't offer the ultimate performance but can do hundreds of thousands of arithmetic operations per second on 256-bit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

recently I'm working on similar project, https://numfi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
>>> from numfi import numfi  
>>> x = numfi(0.68751,1,6,3)
>>> x + 1/3
numfi([1.125]) s7/3-r/s
>>> np.sin(x)
numfi([0.625     ]) s6/3-r/s
```

Comment: @gurkan I'm sorry if this is impropriety in community, but I'm not just "paste same thing". I developed a tool to solve a kind of problem, and provide my solution to these questioners. In each post I show how this work to different question with different example,  I think this is a valid solution, at  least an alternative solution

Comment: @gurkan Understood, I will delete other answer and keep this one

Comment: @gurkan you're right at some point, after review these questions and answers I find that my answers are not 100% fit what questioners want. Some only want floating/fixed transforming, not fixed arithmetic, and some can be solve by simple integer calculation and function, no extra library is need. I will update my answers to better suit their need