# Floats subtraction in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Why is this happening and how do I avoid this issue?

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 27 2013, 09:29:43) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>  0.3 - 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.1
2.7755575615628914e-17
>>> 0.3 - 0.3
0.0
>>> 0.3 - 0.2
0.09999999999999998
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating Point Limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406361/floating-point-limitations) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point) that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small rounding error even before the calculation happens.

[What every programmer should know about floating point: Basic Answers](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

Also, if you're interested in getting around this, check out fixed-point representation. [Python seems to have a variety of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422247/fixed-point-arithmetic).

Comment: The `decimal` module, which is included, seems to be the most indicated solution. From the docs: *"The exactness carries over into arithmetic. In decimal floating point, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3 is exactly equal to zero. In binary floating point, the result is 5.5511151231257827e-017. While near to zero, the differences prevent reliable equality testing and differences can accumulate. For this reason, decimal is preferred in accounting applications which have strict equality invariants."*