# how to convert a float-point number to a fixed-point number with a certain width and precision. Is there any library in python can be used to do this?

Tags: python, math, fixed-point

I need a function to convert a float number to a fixed-point number, represented in binary so that I can put it to the hardware accelerator which can only accept fix-point number. for example, when I input a float number 5.625, giving data width 8, precision 4(4 bits for mantissa), it will return b'01011010, or h'5a or d'90. Is there any functions like this in python libraries?

Comment: Try the built-in `Decimal` module: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422247/fixed-point-arithmetic

Answer (score 5):

That's the same as multiplying by 16 and converting to an int.

```
>>> int(5.625 * (2 ** 4))
90
```

The 16 depends on the number of bits in the precision, but it's easily calculated.

If the number has to go in multiple bytes (like 2 or 4), use the `struct` module. E.g. for 300.625 with 32 data bits, 8 of which are precision:

```
>>> int(300.625 * (2**8))
76960
>>> struct.pack('I', 76960)  # 'I' is 4-byte unsigned int
b'\xaa,\x01\x00'
```

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **fxpmath** in python. You can find info about it at:

https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath

In your example case:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

x = Fxp(5.625, signed=False, n_word=8, n_frac=4)
print(x)         # float value
print(x.bin())   # binary representation
print(x.hex())   # hex repr
print(x.val)     # raw val (decimal of binary stored)
```

Outputs:

> 5.625
>   01011010
>   0x5a
>   90

Answer (score 1):

several fixed point libraries like [numfi](https://numfi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can transform floating point number to fixed point and give bin/dec/hex representation

```
>>> from numfi import numfi
>>> x = numfi(5.625,1,8,4)
>>> x.int # d'90
array([90], dtype=int64)
>>> x.bin # b'01011010
array(['01011010'], dtype='<U8')
>>> x.hex # h'5a
array(['5A'], dtype='<U2')
```

If you prefer simpler solution, you can do quantization yourself:

```py
num = 5.625
w = 8 # data width
f = 4 # fraction width
quantized = np.round(num*(2**f)).astype(int) #note: overflow is not considered here
dec_repr = np.base_repr(quantized, base=10)
bin_repr = np.binary_repr(quantized, width=8)
hex_repr = np.base_repr(quantized, base=16)
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed_8_to_float function is designed to convert a fixed int8 back to a floating-point representation, based on the implementation provided by the user francof2a

```
from fxpmath import Fxp

def fixed_8_to_float(binary):
    sum = 0
    multi = 4
    for i in range(1,8):
        sum = sum + int(binary[i]) * multi
        multi/= 2

    if(int(binary[0])==1):
        sum-=8
    return sum

floating_nums = [1 , -1, 2.34,-2.4,-8,0.42]
fixed_nums = [Fxp(x, signed=True, n_word=8, n_frac=4) for x in floating_nums]
binary_strings = [str(x.bin()) for x in fixed_nums]
hex_strings = [str(x.hex()) for x in fixed_nums ]

print(floating_nums)        
print(binary_strings)   
print(hex_strings)   
print([fixed_8_to_float(x) for x in binary_strings])
```

Outputs:

[1, -1, 2.34, -2.4, -8, 0.42]

['00010000', '11110000', '00100101', '11011010', '10000000', '00000110']

['0x10', '0xF0','0x25', '0xDA', '0x80', '0x06']

[1.0, -1.0, 2.3125, -2.375, -8.0,0.375]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module.

You may pass it a float formatted as a string with required format and precision:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal

>>> '{:5f}'.format(10.0)
'10.000000'

>>> Decimal('{:5f}'.format(10.0))
Decimal('10.000000')
```

Comment: Don't see how that helps with the binary format he's describing.

Comment: As a way to prepare to real format. Next step tweak to topic starter format with Decimal Contexts.

Comment: But the precision you can set with decimal context is in number of base-10 digits, it never maps exactly to a number of bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
def float2fix(val, width, precision):
    integer = abs(int(val * 2 ** precision))
    if val < 0:
        integer = 2 ** (width-1) - integer
    if val >= 0:
        fix_str = bin(integer).replace('0b', '').rjust(width, '0')
    else:
        fix_str = '1'+bin(integer).replace('0b', '').rjust(width-1, '0')
    return fix_str
```